# Masstransit error when try to connect rabbitmq cluster on k8s

Tags: asp.net-core, kubernetes, rabbitmq, masstransit

I have rabbitmq cluster on k8s. I have an application that uses MassTransit with rabbitmq. When I deploy my app to k8s on startup MassTransit writes error. I am sure rabbitmq is reachable because I have also added rabbitmq health check which returns healthy. I shared also service yaml and host information.

Also I can view identity exchange is created from rabbitmq management ui

Startup.cs

```
        var rabbitConfig = new RabbitMqConfig();
        rabbitConfig.Host = Configuration.GetValue<string>("RABBIT_HOST");
        rabbitConfig.UserName = Configuration.GetValue<string>("RABBIT_USER_NAME");
        rabbitConfig.Password = Configuration.GetValue<string>("RABBIT_PASSWORD");
        rabbitConfig.Port = Configuration.GetValue<int>("RABBIT_PORT");

        services.AddSingleton(rabbitConfig);

        var factory = new ConnectionFactory()
        {
            HostName = rabbitConfig.Host,
            Password = rabbitConfig.Password,
            UserName = rabbitConfig.UserName,
            VirtualHost = "/",
            Port = rabbitConfig.Port,
            AutomaticRecoveryEnabled = true
        };

        var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
        services.AddSingleton<IConnection>(connection);

        string connectionString =  Configuration.GetValue<string>("CONNECTION_STRING");

        services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseMySql(connectionString);
        }); 

        services.AddHealthChecks()
            .AddMySql(connectionString, "MySQL")
            .AddRabbitMQ(name: "Rabbit");

        services.AddMassTransit( x=> {   

            x.AddConsumers(typeof(Startup).Assembly);

            x.AddBus(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg => {
                Action<MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.IRabbitMqHostConfigurator> configure = h =>
                {
                    h.Username(rabbitConfig.UserName);
                    h.Password(rabbitConfig.Password);
                };
                cfg.Host(new Uri($"rabbitmq://{rabbitConfig.Host}"),"/", configure);
                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("identity", e=> {
                    e.UseMessageRetry(x => x.Interval(2, 100));                    
                });
            }));
        }); 

        services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, BusService>();
```

Service.yaml

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  namespace:  rabbitmq
  name: rabbitmq
  labels:
    app: rabbitmq
spec:
  selector:
    app: rabbitmq
  ports:
   - name: rabbitmq-mgmt-port
     protocol: TCP
     port: 15672
     targetPort: 15672
   - name: rabbitmq-amqp-port
     protocol: TCP
     port: 5672
     targetPort: 5672
```

host:

```
rabbitmq.rabbitmq.svc.cluster.local
```

When I deploy my application to k8s cluster MassTransit writes error like below.

> MassTransit[0]
>         Operation interrupted: 
>   RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.OperationInterruptedException: The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Peer, code=541, text='INTERNAL_ERROR', classId=0, methodId=0
>      at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SimpleBlockingRpcContinuation.GetReply(TimeSpan timeout)
>      at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.ModelBase.QueueDeclare(String queue, Boolean passive, Boolean durable, Boolean exclusive, Boolean autoDelete, IDictionary`2 arguments)
>      at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.ModelBase.QueueDeclare(String queue, Boolean durable, Boolean exclusive, Boolean autoDelete, IDictionary`2 arguments)
>      at MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Contexts.RabbitMqModelContext.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.b__0()
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Pipeline.ConfigureTopologyFilter`1.ConfigureTopology(ModelContext context)
>      at MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Pipeline.ConfigureTopologyFilter`1.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<<GreenPipes-IFilter<MassTransit-RabbitMqTransport-ModelContext>-Send>b__0>d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at GreenPipes.PipeExtensions.OneTimeSetup[T](PipeContext context, Func`2 setupMethod, PayloadFactory`1 payloadFactory)
>      at MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Pipeline.ConfigureTopologyFilter`1.GreenPipes.IFilter.Send(ModelContext context, IPipe`1 next)
>      at MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Pipeline.ReceiveEndpointFilter.GreenPipes.IFilter<MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.ConnectionContext>.Send(ConnectionContext context, IPipe`1 next)
>      at MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Pipeline.ReceiveEndpointFilter.GreenPipes.IFilter.Send(ConnectionContext context, IPipe`1 next)
>      at GreenPipes.Agents.PipeContextSupervisor`1.GreenPipes.IPipeContextSource.Send(IPipe`1 pipe, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at GreenPipes.Agents.PipeContextSupervisor`1.GreenPipes.IPipeContextSource.Send(IPipe`1 pipe, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at GreenPipes.Agents.PipeContextSupervisor`1.GreenPipes.IPipeContextSource.Send(IPipe`1 pipe, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Transport.RabbitMqReceiveTransport.b__12_0()

Comment: It's most probably your RMQ deployment issue. How have your deployed it to k8s? If you'd used one of the Helm charts, you'd not need a self-baked service file. RMQ 541 error is the internal server error. In addition, you haven't configured your consumers, apart from adding them to the container. Make sure you follow the docs on that https://masstransit-project.com/usage/configuration.html#asp-net-core

Comment: Thanks for response Alexey. Actually I just started project and tried to see actual behavior on my local k8s  cluster that is why I don't have any consumer yet. For rabbitmq deployment I follewed this link https://zupzup.org/k8s-rabbitmq-cluster/. I think you are right, after checking instance logs of rabbitmq cluster I guess it is about deployment.